# supervised classification with fasttext api returns empty array when tested in windows

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, fasttext

I am trying to build a supervised classifier using fast text API. 
My data is 'output.txt' with 15000 rows, 2 columns (gender and name) and 2 classes m/f.

```
__label__F Mary
__label__F Santa
...
__label__M John
```

code:

```
#model = fasttext.load_model('model.bin') # using the default model
classifier = fasttext.supervised('output.txt','model', label_prefix='__label__',thread=8)

labels = classifier.predict('Maria',k=1)
print(labels)
```

when I test with one name it returns

```
[[],[],[],[]]
```

I can't understand where is my mistake. 
I followed the lines of code in [fastext github](https://github.com/salestock/fastText.py/blob/master/README.md). What is the issue creating in windows when the same code is able to work in Linux?

I am using windows, python 3.4x.

Update: 
I have commented the model = fasttext.load .....

so that the learnt supervised classifier model is saved in model.bin. The same code is working in Ubuntu, but not in windows. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: You are not using the object `model` anywhere. Did you mean to use it (not the string `'model'`) as the second argument for `fasttext.supervised`?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you have to install `fasttext-win` as well:

```
pip install fasttext-win
```

See here: https://pypi.org/project/fasttext-win/

Answer (score -1):

I guess that the reason you get an array as an answer is that it looks like *predict* would like to have a list as argument.

```
    labels = classifier.predict(['Maria'],k=1)
```

But unfortunately I have no idea why the offered labels are empty. I'm getting the same problem under Windows (*model.labels* returns an empty list).

Comment: If you dont know the solution why are you answering it as an answer ?